# Leveraging Windows Azure with ClickOnce publishing

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, azure, clickonce

I have been developing a small C#/WinForm utility in my spare time and have got to the point where it's ready for release. My [previous](http://mspointsconverter.codeplex.com/) project was hosted via CodePlex which allowed me to update my source code and manually upload new versions via my computer.

I've recently recieved an [MSDN subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/default.aspx) which gives me a fairly [generous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/ee461076.aspx) amount of usage/storage with Windows Azure.

This got me thinking, I know ClickOnce allows applications to be installed via the internet but would it be possible to do so whilst using Azure to host it?

I would like to think that this would allow me to update my application and push it to Azure whilst updating my source code on CodePlex via Team Foundation Server.

Does anybody have any experience in this? Is it something that can even be done?

Thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Kazi Nadudvari's Blog and see if this post helps:

[How to deploy ClickOnce applications to Windows Azure?](http://kazinadudvari.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/how-to-deploy-clickonce-applications-to-windows-azure/)

Comment: Also this link may also be helpful: http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-host-a-clickonce-deployment-in-azure-blob-storage/

Comment: Here is a MSDN blogs link answering this very question: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/09/how-to-deploy-clickonce-application-using-windows-azure-storage-in-very-simple-steps.aspx